# flashdata not working in codeiginter Getting empty data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am setting some data in a action of controller but I am not able to get in another action

```
public function add()
    {
$this->session->set_flashdata('check_id',$details['user_id']);
        $data['main'] = 'test';
        $this->load->view('test/layout', $data);
}

public function post()
    {
$check_id =  $this->session->flashdata('check_id');
}
```

User will submit a form from add action view and after form will submit to post action but here I am getting $check_id is empty. It was working earlier but when I setup all code on new server then it is not working

Comment: do you know what the method  set_flashdata in session in codeigniter ? this is documentations https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#id11

Comment: @PascalTovohery - I think you need to be more specific than just linking to the documentation, seeing that they seem to do as it says.

Comment: When you do set_flashdata that set session in few periode of time, and that will desapear after. And you wouldnt see it after. A suggest you using set_userdata.

Comment: I don't know the reason,
but every time using CI3,
i use third party https://packagist.org/packages/ajani/flash-message.

Comment: @PascalTovohery same code is working on other server. Any configuration related issue?

Comment: Try logging the flash data into your view, see if it is present there? And what is in $details?

Comment: *same code is working on other server.* most likely you have different CI / PhP versions on that servers, maybe not even compatible. Please let us know those settings!